# Indent SAS program codes

Tags: sas, indentation

I have an entire program written but it is not indented or formatted as SAS Enterprise Guide does it or as the professionals do it.

Is there way to automatically indent/reformat the entire program to make it look more professional?

Comment: Just a note: the portion of this asking for a macro is off-topic for this site.  You're welcome to ask about program functionality (as my answer addresses) but not to ask for a pre-written code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Enterprise Guide, there is an auto-indenting function. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> will automatically format/indent your code for you.

I'm not aware of any method using SAS Display Manager (DM - often called Base SAS).  You could look online for macros users have written, or perhaps more easily simply open EG, open your program, format it, and save it back as a .sas file.

SAS Studio also contains this functionality, and is available free as part of SAS University Edition.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to the enterprise guide. That, is the biggest problem. That is why I am hoping there is a macro to auto indent programs.

Comment: SAS Studio also contains the formatter, and is available free for download as part of SAS University Edition.

Comment: Will try that out. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EMACS for your editor then I think the ESS package has a formatting option.

https://ess.r-project.org/index.php?Section=home